# Parse product price using xpath

Tags: xpath, shopify

I'm having a problem to parse price of the product from this page ironflask.com/products/14-oz-wide-mouth-with-straw-lid?variant=31659847057496

```
<div class="p-price">
   Price:
     <dl class="price" data-price="">$17.95</dl>
</div>
```

I have tried: `//div[class='p-price']/dl[class='price']` and `//div[class='p-price']/dl[class='price']/text()`
nothing seems to work

Comment: `//div[@class='p-price']/dl[@class='price']` - note the `@` before each attribute.

Comment: @RobC Sorry, forgot about @ here. I tried with @ before each atr, it still doesn't parse price. Managed to parse everything(img,description,title) but stuck with the price.

Comment: @RobC Finally I have managed to parse the price like that:  `//meta[@property='og:price:amount']/@content`   :)